# Exception on finishing an activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I've a list of some items & whenever I click on any of them I go to a new intent accordingly. But when I try to return to the list again then some items are giving correct result while others are giving errors.

I've already tried calling finish() in onDestroy & onStop method in the intents which are giving an error. I've also tried commenting out both of those methods because that should get out of stack by default. But LogCat shows

```
01-12 23:04:55.050: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop    activity {com.balance.start/com.balance.start.GFX}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-12 23:04:55.050: E/AndroidRuntime(14445):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3613)
01-12 23:04:55.050: E/AndroidRuntime(14445):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3679)
01-12 23:04:55.050: E/AndroidRuntime(14445):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2900(ActivityThread.java:126)
01-12 23:04:55.050: E/AndroidRuntime(14445):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2071)
01-12 23:04:55.050: E/AndroidRuntime(14445):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-12 23:04:55.050: E/AndroidRuntime(14445):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-12 23:04:55.050: E/AndroidRuntime(14445):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
01-12 23:04:55.050: E/AndroidRuntime(14445):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 23:04:55.050: E/AndroidRuntime(14445):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-12 23:04:55.050: E/AndroidRuntime(14445):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
01-12 23:04:55.050: E/AndroidRuntime(14445):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-12 23:04:55.050: E/AndroidRuntime(14445):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 23:04:55.050: E/AndroidRuntime(14445): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-12 23:04:55.050: E/AndroidRuntime(14445):    at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:3869)
01-12 23:04:55.050: E/AndroidRuntime(14445):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3608)
```

This is my code..

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.report_ledger);
        ...
    }

class MyAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
        super(context, c, autoRequery);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context ctxt, Cursor c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        TextView tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAB1);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAB2);
        TextView tv3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAB3);
        TextView tv4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAB4);
        TextView tv5 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAB5);
        tv1.setText(c.getString(2));
        tv2.setText("" + c.getDouble(3));
        tv3.setText("" + c.getDouble(4));
        tv4.setText("" + (c.getDouble(4) - c.getDouble(3)));
        tv5.setText((c.getDouble(3) > c.getDouble(4) ? "CR." : "DR."));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        return inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.text_view_for_list_view_account_balance, parent,
                false);
    }
}
```

I've not implemented onClickListener for back button because I don't think that is required. I think system should finish the activity by itself. :/

Thanks.

Comment: Show us the code for those methods.

Comment: Raghav which code are you asking for?
That is a very lengthy code. So.. I'm putting up the code which might be the cause of error.

Comment: Why are you calling `finish()` in `onDestroy()`? `onDestroy()` is called when the system is finishing your activity. There's no purpose to call `finish()` again and may, in fact, be the source of the null pointer.

Comment: I didn't implement it at first & it was showing that null pointer error & that's why I added those methods.

Comment: Should I call the new intents with StartActivityForResult but I don't think that's the reason for the error because StartActivityForResult is called when we want something from the next activity I think. :o

Comment: I can't believe this.. the error was because of 
startManagingCursor(ourCursor);
   adapter = new MyAdapter(Ledger.this, ourCursor, false);

Comment: there's no need to call onDestroy() and finish(). remove them, then post the error if any

Comment: & when I commented out startManagingCursor(ourCursor);
It started working. :o
Can anyone please explain this to me? Why did that happen?

Comment: Okay. This was the cause of error.

[Activity Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startManagingCursor(android.database.Cursor))

Comment: I've one more doubt if anybody could help me with that please.
I want to view my database without rooting my phone. I've tried to copy my db to my sdcard & I think that worked because I didn't see any error but I'm unable to find where that file has gone.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you are calling `finish()` in `onDestroy()`. Actually `finish()` need to be called when you want to `finish()` your activity, where `onDestroy()` method called automatically. instead of this you can make your intents or other objects to null in `onDestroy()` if needed.